# Vue js select option not appearing due to v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Ok so i am working on some code which allows a user to change the store they belong to. I am using a  tag and in it i have a v-model. in the  tag i use a for loop to give the stores the user can choose from.

Here is my code:

```
<div v-if="contestant.stores.length > 1" class="mt-10 col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="riot_account_store"  v-on:change="onChangeStore()">
        <option v-for="store in contestant.stores" :key="store.objectId" :value="store.objectId">{{ store.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

All i want now is to add an "unchanged" default value to appear FIRST before all the choices. Basically a simple `<option>unchanged</option>` nothing special. Problem is when i add any other option it is simply skipped. It does still appear if i hit the select and it appears above the first choice from the loop. So it is being compiled just not "chosen" as a first value. No idea what the problem is. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your option needs a value. That's it:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    riot_account_store: null,
    stores: [
      { objectId: 12, name: 'Foo' },
      { objectId: 13, name: 'Bam' },
      { objectId: 14, name: 'Baz' },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeStore() {
      console.log(this.riot_account_store);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="stores.length > 1" class="mt-10 col-sm-10">
    <p>Selected: {{ riot_account_store }}</p>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="riot_account_store"  v-on:change="onChangeStore()">
          <option :value="null">unselect</option>
          <option v-for="store in stores" :key="store.objectId" :value="store.objectId">{{ store.name }}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your default `option`, assign a `value` that is not taken and init your `v-model` with value. Vue binding will take care of the rest.

```
<div v-if="contestant.stores.length > 1" class="mt-10 col-sm-10">
 <select class="form-control" v-model="riot_account_store"  v-on:change="onChangeStore()">
    <option value="not_taken_id">default</option>
    <option v-for="store in contestant.stores" :key="store.objectId" :value="store.objectId">{{ store.name }}</option>
 </select>
</div>

date () {
  return {
    riot_account_store: 'not_taken_id'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the 'initial' selection somewhere, for example in the data-block:

```
data() {
    return {
        initialSelection: { objectId: 10, name: 'Generic store name' } // you can set this property for example in the mounted() lifecycle-hook
    }
```

Then edit your -Tag to:

```
<option v-for="store in contestant.stores" :key="store.objectId" :value="store.objectId">{{ store.objectId === initialSelection.objectId ? 'unchanged' : store.name }}</option>
```